# WordPress How to Keep the_content filter for my cpt from affecting other posts on the same page

Tags: wordpress

I am using a custom post type for the slide in my theme. I'm trying to remove wpautop from the cpt using the_content filter hook, and it works using the following code, but it also removes it wpautop from the other queries on the same page. Here is the code:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_autop_for_post_type', 0 );

function remove_autop_for_post_type( $content )
{
if('par2_slide' === get_post_type(get_the_ID())){
    remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
    return $content;
};
return $content;
};
```

Adding a second condition to include "! is_main_query() like so:

```
if('par2_slide' === get_post_type(get_the_ID()) && ! is_main_query()){
```

causes the script to stop working. The query for my cpt to which this is supposed to apply is as follows:

```
function par2_slides_query () {
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'par2_slide');
$slides_loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $slides_loop->have_posts() ) : $slides_loop->the_post();
echo '<li class="slide">';
the_content();
echo '</li>';
endwhile;
};
```

wpauto messes with the slide layout so I really need to filter the content for that particular post type to turn it off without turning it off for the instances of the_content on the rest of the page.  It doesn't affect other pages, on the_content on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Re add the filter after your `IF` statement.

`add_filter('the_content', 'wpautoop');`

It removes it and returns the content IF `par2_slide` is the post type, and if it's not it adds the filter if it doesn't exist.